# update function not working with where condition

Tags: cakephp

```
if($mydetails=$this->Mydetails->findBydoctor_id($id)){//to update
        $this->set('mydetails', $mydetails);
         if ($this->request->is('post')) {

              if ($this->Mydetails->updateAll($this->request->data, array('doctor_id' => "'".$id."'"))) {
                $this->Session->setFlash(__('Your Details has updated.'));
            } else {
                $this->Session->setFlash(__('Unable to updated.'));
            }
             }
            //print_r($mydetails);

            }//
```

here i am trying to do update the form details using id but it not worked

Comment: here errors shows as  `Error: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'Mydetails.Mydetails' in 'field list'`

Comment: your code is totally mess... Read Cakephp documentation and practice well....

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to use Cake's magic methods

```
$this->Mydetails->findBydoctor_id($id)
```

It should be :

```
$this->Mydetails->findByDoctorId($id)
```

Give that at try